# try/except and context managers

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to make my try/except blocks as small as possible. However, I don't know how to reconcile this with a potentially lengthy `with` block:

```
try:
    with db.connect() as connection:
        # many lines interacting with the database
        # and more lines
        # and yet more lines

except ConnectionError:
```

Is there a way to write the try/except so it isn't so long?

I suppose I could reorganize most of the code into a separate function:

```
try:
    with db.connect() as connection:
        do_stuff(connection)
except ConnectionError:
```

...but it seems like there should be a way to do it in fewer lines.

Comment: I would probably go with [programmers.se] -- questions that are matters of design sensibility and opinion are more welcome there, whereas Stack Overflow prefers to deal in the specific and concrete and avoid matters of opinion or taste. See the guidance for selecting a Stack Exchange site at [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: The function call is probably the best solution.

Comment: I'd second Barmar, the function call is appropriate in most cases. Except if this code is serving requests, then it would be better to maintain a connection pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to put the `with` statement in the `try` statement, if `db.connect` is the only thing that can raise the `ConnectionError`. If there is a connection error, there's no connection to close.

```
try:
    connection = db.connect()
except ConnectionError:
    ...

with connection:
    ...
```

It's not the call to `db.connect` itself that the `with` statement cares about; it's the calls to `connection.__enter__` and `connection.__exit__`.

Depending on what you *do* about the `ConnectionError`, the `with` statement should probably be guarded to avoid trying to use the undefined name `connection`.

---

If you don't like the idea of being able to do something with `connection` between it being assigned and the `with` statement, you can use an `ExitStack` to enter the context immediately. For example,

```
from contextlib import ExitStack


with ExitStack() as es:
    try:
        connection = es.enter_context(db.connect())
    except ConnectionError:
        ...

    # do stuff with the connection
```

Comment: Ah ha!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!